# How do I create an Excel table with a blank header

Tags: excel, excel-tables

I have an Excel table that summarizes data from a TFS query using `COUNTIFS()` statements.  It works great until I get to the end and I want to use a blank value to display a count of the blanks.  For the row values I can just type an apostrophe and the value remains blank (row 7 below) but in a header it replaces the apostrophe with `'Column1`  (see column E below)...

[image]

Before you say, "why don't you use a Pivot Table?" let me answer that I have done just that.  The problem lies in the next step wherein I want to display the data in SharePoint which does not seem to recognize Pivot Tables but does recognize regular tables.

Can I do this without VBA?

Comment: I just created a new column on a structured table using alt+enter (line feed or char(10)) as the column header. Will this suffice?

Comment: @Jeeped well, it worked but my "countifs" statement doesn't agree.  Alt+Enter left a blank but not a real blank and Char(10) leaves a zero (0).

Answer (score 2):

Incase you still need an answer to this. I have just found that putting a space as the header makes it appear blank.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As @Thomas mentions, a space character for the header text will appear visibly blank.

This will likely be fine for your case, but if you have multiple columns that you'd like to have blank (as I do just now) then the text needs to be unique across the headers and single space characters will result in showing a number for subsequent headers.

The 2 options I've found in that case:

1. Add an additional space character to each additional column (so the second column gets 2 space characters, the 3rd gets 3 etc)
2. Change the header text colour to match the cell colour

I went with 2 as the quickest option